# Cómo subir una imagen a Firebase Storae con Android Storage?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, local-storage

> Esto lo hice con un tutorial del 2016

tal vez haya cambiado la configuración de Android Studio, sin embargo no encuentro nuevos videos sobre esto, si conoces de un canal con tutoriales actualizados te agradecería que me lo dejes en la descripción

```
private Button mButton;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private TextView nombre;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ImageView jeje;
private StorageReference mstorage;
private FloatingActionButton uplstorage;
private static final int Gallery_Intent = 2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantallaprincipal);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mstorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("bucket");

    uplstorage = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.efe);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cerrarsei);
    nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    jeje = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mtb);
```

*//Esta parte solo era para poner la imagen con borde circular*

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.usuario);
    RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap);
    roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
    jeje.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
```

*//esta parte es para seleccionar la foto en la galeria*

```
    uplstorage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,Gallery_Intent);
        }
    });
```

*//Esta es para cerrar sesión*

```
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(Pantallaprincipal.this, Inicio.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    getUserInfo();
}
```

**//Aquí supuestamente se podía subir la foto al Storage**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == Gallery_Intent && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        StorageReference filePath = mstorage.child("bucket").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(Pantallaprincipal.this, "Cargado exitosamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**//Esta parte es solo para identificar el nombre del usuario con la Database**

```
private void getUserInfo() {

    String id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase.child("User").child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue().toString();

                nombre.setText(name);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

No sé qué estaré haciendo mal, pueden corregir mi codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase cambio la forma de subir elementos al storage, para actualizar el código deberias usar lo siguiente

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg"); // Referencia a donde queres subir el archivo 
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continuamos con el task para obtener la url de descarga
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            String urlFoto = downloadUri.toString();
        } else {
            // Manejar fallos
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Este es el código que podes usar para subir un archivo, en `ref.putFile(file)` es donde vas a colocar la imagen a subir .

> El método putFile() infiere el tipo de MIME de forma automática a
>   partir de la extensión de File, pero puedes especificar contentType en
>   los metadatos para anular el tipo detectado.

Podes leer un poco mas en la documentación para alguna duda

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?hl=es-419#get_a_download_url